# Discord.py Check authors message and content

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

**Is there a way I can check if a user send a message twice (same content) and then to not let him send a message for 10 sec? 10 sec is an example**

Comment: Did you try anything in code ?

Comment: no i did not try something

Comment: First, you have to be more specific about that, Send a message twice ( repeated message ) about what interval you want to be check. what did you try to do? No one here is going to give you complete code
to start `save the most recent message of every user to a JSON file, iterate through it to look for duplicate message `

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [what's on-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953), and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: "Implement this feature for me" is off-topic for this site. You have to make an honest attempt, and then ask a **specific question** about your algorithm or technique. If you have no idea where to start, you need to look up a tutorial or talk to a tutor. Stack Overflow is the wrong place to ask for general advice

Answer (score 0):

You can save the message in your main code as a variable, then on the next message check if the previous message is identical to the current one and add a role to mute him, then after 10secs remove the role.

Example:

```
import asyncio

first_message = True

bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    global msg
    msg = message
    first_message = False

    if not first_message and msg == message:
        await message.delete()
        role = await bot.get_role(ROLE_ID)
        await message.author.add_role(role)

        await asyncio.sleep(10)
        
        await message.author.remove_role(role)
```

Therefor you would need to create a for example muted role which's ID you enter as ROLE_ID